# Why Gauss distribution is a necessary condition for the equality of maximum likelihood estimate and sample mean

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I'm reading *Probability Theory: The Logic of Science* by Jaynes. And while I'm reading section 7.3, he proofed that Gauss distribution is a necessary condition for the equality of maximum likelihood estimate and sample mean.

But he just derived Gauss distribution from a special case of sample mean, how does that imply a necessary condition? It is like if we know `a + b = 0`,then we assume `a = 1, b = -1`, from this special case we get `a - b = 2`, but that doesn't implies `a - b = 2` is a necessary condition of `a + b = 0`.

( You may read [Chapter 7 of this book online](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheoryChapter7.pdf) if you don't have this book).

Comment: The proof in Jaynes is rather awfully documented. You can find a more interesting [reference here][1], in particular check out "The Proof" on page 105-106. 

In particular, the heart of the "proof" relies on the assumption that the maximum likelihood equation holds for *all* samples, in particular the adhoc choice that Jaynes gives.


  [1]: http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheoryChapter7.pdf

Comment: @AlexR. : Thanks. But I think you've give the wrong link, it is the link of Jaynes' proof, which is in my question.

Comment: Whoops. Here's the right link: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/stahl96.pdf